# bcmath operations with very small numbers

Tags: php, bcmath

I want to use bcmath for precise operations with very small numbers, but it fails. I am trying to calculate cryptocurrency prices and thought that bcmath is better than converting float to integers

**This working:**

php > echo number_format(0.000005 * 0.0025, 10);

0.0000000125

**And this is not working:**

php > echo number_format(bcmul(0.000005, 0.0025, 10), 10);

0.0000000000

php > echo number_format(bcadd(0.000005, 0.00000025, 10), 10);

0.0000000000

**Is there some configurations for bcmath or this is normal behavior?**

Comment: wrapping the number with string as said in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the bc* function arguments as strings. Otherwise, they're interpreted as native floats and subject to the limits thereof.

```
echo bcmul('0.000005', '0.0025', 10), "\n";
echo number_format(bcmul('0.000005', '0.0025', 10), 10), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
0.0000000125
0.0000000125
```